# Fetching the data from database for specific time

Tags: c#

Hello here i want fetch the data from database  into datagridview for timer interval
 BETWEEN `1900-01-01 23:00:00.000` AND `1900-01-01 06:59:59.999` but here i am unable to do that can anyone help me  .......

```
temprature Time                         date
27         1900-01-01 00:46:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
27.3       1900-01-01 00:48:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
27.6       1900-01-01 00:50:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
27.9       1900-01-01 00:52:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
28.2       1900-01-01 00:54:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
28.5       1900-01-01 00:56:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
28.8       1900-01-01 00:58:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
29.1       1900-01-01 01:00:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
29.4       1900-01-01 01:02:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
29.7       1900-01-01 01:04:09.000  2011-06-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: Can you elaborate doesn't make any sense with what is **here**

Comment: Appu, what is the data type of the Time column in your database?

Comment: sir i am  using SQL database datatype of the column time is 'datetime'

Answer (score 2):

This question is heavily dependent on which database you have, but I'll take a wild shoot over here, I'm assuming that you're using [Ado.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) and have a [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) database, to get those rows, you should do something like this:

```
// your connection string should be like
// Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDbName;Integrated Security=True
var connectionString = "A connection string";

var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var query = new SqlCommand("SELECT temperature, startDate, endDate FROM yourTable", connection);

connection.Open();
var dbReader = query.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);

Console.WriteLine("Temperature\tTime\tDate");

while (dbReader.Read())
{
    var row = new object[dbReader.FieldCount];
    dbReader.GetValues(row);

    var temperature= row[0].ToString();
    var startDate = DateTime.Parse(row[1]);
    var endDate = DateTime.Parse(row[2]);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", temperature, startDate, endDate);
}
```

Again, this answer is assuming a lot of things about your question, because you should have specified your database type, the columns of your table and how you're accesing the database, but with any luck, this code may be a starting point for you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 (already voted though) This is what I love about SO, that even if the question is so incomplete, there are folks always willing to answer and who actually do so.

Comment: thanks @Mamta, I know that is an incomplete question, but is by no means an excuse to not try to help.. thanks for the upvote :)